# How can my image take all the button's size in Swift

Tags: swift, storyboard

[StoryBoard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sogw3.jpg)

I just need to know how can an image can take all the button's size. All my button's background image are so small

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
ImageButton.imageView?.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
```

or

```
ImageButton.imageView?.contentMode = .scaleToFill
```